# RestAssured - want to verify the body structure of JSON response in RestAssured

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath, json-path-expression

When i request for GET request, I'm getting the JSON response, but here my requirement is to validate the structure of response body.

For example:

```
{
   "lotto":{
      "lottoId":5,
      "winning-numbers":[2,45,34,23,7,5,3],
      "winners":[
         {
            "winnerId":23,
            "numbers":[2,45,34,23,3,5]
         },
         {
            "winnerId":54,
            "numbers":[52,3,12,11,18,22]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

The above response having structure, so i need to validate structure instead of one key value pair, how i can achieve this?

Comment: Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to verify json-schema matching.

Firstly, you need to add this dependency to your pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/json-schema-validator -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then you need to create a file json-schema-your-name.json with structure like that:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "data": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "flow_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 36,
            "maxLength": 36
          },
          "flow_org_id": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [ "flow_id", "flow_org_id" ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There are a bunch of services which generate schemas based on json - eg - [this one](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-json-to-schema-converter)

Once schema file is ready, you need to provide a path to your file in a String format - eg -

```
private static final String GET_SUBSCRIPTION_JSON_SCHEMA_PATH =
    "json/schemas/GetSubscriptionByIdSchema.json";
```

And invoke `matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("your/path/to/json-schema")` method for assertion.

**UPD:**

So the flow will basically be like:

- you have a schema file somewhere in project dir (and know its path)
- you hit the endpoint in some test method
- you match the response you've received with the schema file

Practically, it will look following:

```
  @Test
  public void someTestMethod() {
    Response responseToValidate = // here you should assign and store returned response
    
    responseToValidate
      .assertThat()      
      .statusCode(200)
      .body("json.path.to.needed.key", equalTo("123"))
```

.body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("path/to/your/schema/in/string/format"));
}

Comment: I have one question, if we are hitting the request and we are getting the response and I'm trying to create schema with the help of response and use as suggested by you. My question is my schema will be coming from where? One hand i have response of api but on other hand the schema, how do i get that? So that i can validate my response and schema both are valid?

Comment: @ShivkumarDubey I've updated my answer with real example, check it out.

Comment: Thanks for giving more depth details that i have understood now. But my question didn't answered if suppose I'm getting json response of 10 values data and i want to verify for only one not all 10 data so how i can do that? @Villa_7

Comment: @ShivkumarDubey In topic you said "...to validate the structure of response body.", so I advised you that.
Json-schema approach is not suitable for validating specific value.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, really appreciate it, if you could also let me know how i can validate my api response with database values?

Comment: @ShivkumarDubey yeah, I've updated the answer just now. See "@Test" method.
It will require Json-path and Hamcrest dependencies for validating like above.